# What is the difference between the mongo-php-library and the MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb

What is the difference between the mongo-php-library and the MongoDB driver?
How are they different in terms of performance and features? What are the pros and cons?

We are currently using the "mongo-php-library" in production like this:

```
$connection = (new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://user:password@mongo:27017"));

$client = $connection->selectDatabase("the_database");

$collection_users = $client->selectCollection('users');
```

Are there any up or downsides connecting to a database like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) (written in PHP) is a high-level abstraction around the lower-level [MongoDB PHP driver (mongodb extension)](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver). MongoDB driver mongodb is written in C and provides only a minimal API for core driver functionality: commands, queries, writes, connection management, and BSON serialization. Therefore PHP developers will need  mongo-php-library to provide the easy-to-use higher level APIs, such as query builders, individual command helper methods, and GridFS.

mongo-php-library is officially supported by MongoDB. There is no issue or concern to its performance and features as it's the only choice, unless you decide to develop yourself a customized/optimized library, which may ends up in reinventing the same wheel.

Previously [the legacy MongoDB PHP driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy) provides instead the high level APIs, but MongoDB decide to supersede it with current mongodb extension, so the legacy driver only supports up to PHP 5.6 and MongoDB 3.0. The reason for this is unknown, but we guess MongoDB wants to keep the MongoDB PHP driver at low level and develops a PHP library on top of this to facilitate their support for PHP 7 and subsequent PHP upgrades.

Comment: So you technically don't need the library then, but the driver would be required so that your SAPI can actually connect to a remote DB, right? Would the library just be convenient bc of syntactical sugar? Thanks

Comment: @user2402616 technically you don't need library. But practically the library should save you time to develop your web application.

Comment: Sweet, I'll have to look into it.  Yes - code examples for library seem to offer advantages. Native mongodb php code was not trivial to write in as opposed to its Node-based equivalents.